# problem with href

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my anchor tag.

For example I have:

```
<a href="#">abc</a>
```

Then output is `abc (#)`.Whatever i write inside href attribute comes along with a tag.
Dont know what's wrong with the code.

Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: The output … from what? A browser? Do you have a stylesheet that applies the attribute value in :after?

Comment: yes in a browser...and i do have a stylesheet.but in that i have applied standard properties like a {cursor:pointer}. i have used blueprint css framework.m using firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something in your css along the lines of:

```
a:link:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
}
```

You might want to add a style block to the head of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">

a:after { content: ""; }

</style>
```

And see if that makes a difference.

Are you hand-coding the html, or is this generated by a template/cms?

Comment: hey thnx a lot...actually the framework file which m using has this code  a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}...so after commenting its working fine.thnx again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem you are having is. I copied that line of html into a file, named it test.html, and opened it with IE and Chrome. Both just have a link labeled ***abc*** on screen that links to "#".

What do you see when you just use that line in a file?
Are you using some sort of browser plugin that displays the url of links?

Comment: i'm not using any browser pulgin...and this problem is coming in chrome also.whenever i remove href attribute and it displays perfectly....but wen i use href and the content in href comes along with the a tag..

Comment: m using bluprint css framework...will dat be a issue?

Comment: Copy your CSS from the file that is giving you trouble and paste it into your question. Also, try to work on your grammar. This isn't Facebook.

Comment: got the solution for it..removed this line in CSS a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}....thanks anyways..and sorry..actually was in hurry to know the answer !!!